# Using Loop to find Brute Force Prime Numbers using Mersenne Number (Python) (Why isn't my code working?)

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write this program that uses looping where it finds Brute Force Prime Numbers using Mersenne. The direction is as follows.

> > > > A prime number is a number that is not evenly divisible by any other number (except,       trivially, 1). All known methods of determining whether a number is a prime number rely on brute force, that is, exhaustive testing of the possibilities. Write a routine that checks whether a number is prime. Check if it’s even, and if not, check all the odd numbers up to the square root of the number (do you see why the square root is enough?). If the number is not prime, tell the user one factor.
> > > >
> > > > For you demo, you’ll use Mersenne 67, which is 2 to the 67th power minus 1 (see problem 1-4-A): 147573952589676412927 [147,573,952,589,676,412,927]. In 1644, Marin Mersenne conjectured this number was prime. It was not until 1903 that F.N. Cole resolved this conjecture, for which he received a standing ovation at a meeting of the American Mathematical Society. What was the resolution? (i.e., is Mersenne 67 prime?) Use your program to answer this question; your program will probably run for about 2½ minutes, quite an advance over the 2½ centuries it originally took to resolve the issue.

This what what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to run where I can verify my answer. Any inputs would greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
def me():
    N = int(input("What is the Value of N?="))
    Mersenne=(2**N)-1
    print(format(Mersenne,',d'))

me()


def is_prime(n):

if is_even(n):

else:

    for f in <something that generates odd numbers>:
        if is_factor(f,n):


def get_n():
n = raw_input("What is the value of n? ")
return ((2 ** 67)-1) if n == 'm' else int(n)


n = get_n()  
p = is_prime(n)

if p:
  print("%d is not prime (e.g. factor=%d)" % (n, p))
else:
  print("%d is prime")
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just changed it. Please help if you can. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I strongly suggest you contact your instructor or teaching assistant. If you are stuck on `<something that generates odd numbers>` and `if is_even(n): else:` You'll be crushed before mid-terms.

Comment: This is for own benefit. Would you be able to show me an example if possible? Thank you

Comment: @msw : The OP's inability to Google doesn't bode well, either...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It passes pylint and pep8, and it runs on python 2.[4567] and python 3.[01234].

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

'''Test if a number is prime'''

# pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
# superfluous-parens: Parentheses are good for clarity and portability

import math


def is_factor(numerator, denominator):
    '''Return true if numerator is evenly divisible by denominator'''
    if numerator % denominator == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def is_even(number):
    '''Return true if numerator is evenly divisible by 2'''
    return is_factor(number, 2)


def odds_to(maximum):
    '''Return odd numbers up to maximum'''
    number = 3
    while number <= maximum:
        yield number
        number += 2


def get_factor(number):
    '''
    Return the lowest factor of number.
    If number is prime, return 0
    '''
    if is_even(number):
        return 2
    else:
        top = int(math.sqrt(number))
        for odd_number in odds_to(top):
            if is_factor(number, odd_number):
                return odd_number
        return 0


def get_number():
    '''Return the value of Mersenne 67'''
    # number = 11
    # number = 6
    # number = 15
    number = 2 ** 67 - 1
    return number


def main():
    '''Main function'''
    number = get_number()
    factor = get_factor(number)

    if factor == 0:
        print("%d is prime" % number)
    else:
        print("%d is not prime (e.g. factor=%d)" % (number, factor))

main()
```

Comment: Shoot. I'm using an online complier and it has difficulty running it. Would you be able to tell me out the output is with Merseene 67?

Comment: `if condition: return True` `else: return False` is a tad verbose, don't you think?

Comment: According to the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences A000043](https://oeis.org/A000043), 67 **is not** a Mersenne exponent.